# Using same consumer group for different kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two different kafka topics T1 and T2, both having one consumer each C1 and C2 respectively. C1 and C2 have the same consumer group G1. Now, if C1 dies, will C2 consumes message from both the topics T1 and T2 ?

Answer (score 1):

No, As your

- C1 is configured to read only from topic T1 and
- C2 is configured to read only from topic T2

Even though group id is same for both the consumers it works fine as while checking the last committed offset, it will be checked against groupid and topic.

As topics here are different T1 & T2, consumers C1 & C2 consumes only from the respective topics T1 & T2.

To your question "If C1 dies, whether C2 will consume from T1 ?".
No, as C2 did not subscribe the T2 topic. So, irrespective of same or different groupid, C2 doesnt consume from T1 as it did not subscribe it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you also tell what will happen to topic T1 when C1 dies. As it was the only consumer T1 had, will the message stay in the topic for the retention time and disappear, or will a new consumer get assigned for the topic.

Comment: yes, considering you have only consumer C1 - when C1 dies, data in topic retains until the retention time. Unless, you restart C1 or spinup another consumer with same or different group, data will not be consumed from the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka will store the last committed offset of `G1` group consumer thread (which is `C1`) before it die, and then hence any new consumer thread like either `C2` or `CX..` belonging to `G1` group will start consuming from the last offset committed by `C1`

Comment: So does that mean, after C1 dies, C2 which was consuming only from T2 will start consuming from both T1 and T2  ?